# Replacing part of a triangle matrix by a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector, replace

I have `v<- c(2,4,5)` and `mat<- matrix(0,n,n)`.
and i want to replace vector in the upper of the matrix, each place which i identify, the arrays are replacing as length number of vector. for example ,for n=5 the output can be :

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    4    0    0
[2,]    0    0    5    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I try with this code:

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in 1:5){
    if (i<j & j<= 5){
      mat [upper.tri(mat, diag = FALSE)]<- v
    }
  }
}
```

but output is:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    4    2    2
[2,]    0    0    5    4    4
[3,]    0    0    0    5    5
[4,]    0    0    0    0    2
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I have two problems:

1. I want the vector replaced just one time in matrix and not to repeat.
2. I don't know where I have to replace i and j in the loop for the starting point of matrix to replace vector.(maybe I want to start the vector from [3,4] in matrix.).for example:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    2    4
[4,]    0    0    0    0    5
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fill matrices from vectors, two good things to know:

1. It fills them in by-column; and
2. If the vector is shorter than the portion of the matrix to fill, then the vector will be recycled (repeated).

Further, in your code, you use two `for` loops, nested, with the apparent intent of operating only on those indices within the matrix ... but then you do not reference `i` and `j` in the matrix subset or assignment, so every time it tries to replace a single value, it's replacing the entire matrix upper-tri with the entire vector.

Here's a speedier way:

```r
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
v <- c(2, 4, 5)
mat[upper.tri(mat)][seq_along(v)] <- v
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    2    4    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    5    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

The first indexing on `mat` is the upper-triangle, as you know. The second subsets to just `length(v)` of that subset.

If you want to replace it at arbitrary places in the upper-triangle, though, here's a shot:

```r
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
ut <- upper.tri(mat)
fullv <- integer(sum(ut)) # the size of the matrix subset
fullv
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
fullv[5 + seq_along(v)] <- v
fullv
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 2 4 5 0 0
mat[ut] <- fullv
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    4
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    5
# [3,]    0    0    0    2    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Here we demonstrate that the filling is being done *by column*, which is not what you were asking for. To better see how this filling is happening,

```r
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
ut <- upper.tri(mat)
mat[ut] <- seq_len(sum(ut))
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    2    4    7
# [2,]    0    0    3    5    8
# [3,]    0    0    0    6    9
# [4,]    0    0    0    0   10
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

So if you want your `v` in very specific places and they are not consecutive per this ordering, then you'll need to be specific:

```r
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
ut <- upper.tri(mat)
mat[ut][c(6,9,10)] <- v
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    2    4
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    5
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Just do the third code block again with a different sub-vector. For instance, if you first did `mat[ut][c(1,2,3)] <- v`, then do `mat[ut][c(6,9,10)] <- c(8,9,10)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the `{r,c}` indices for each element of a length `n` vector (you will also need the dimensions of a square triangle required to fit such a vector.

For example, for a length 3 vector starting at {3,4} (assuming column-major as in R), you will need the indices

```
i r c
1 3,4

2 3,5
3 4,5

4 3,6
5 4,6
6 5,6
...
```

You can probably see the patterns already. For the rows, there is a common r function which gives the pattern `3 3 4 3 4 5 ...` which is `sequence` specifically `sequence(1:3) + 2`.

Next the columns have a simpler solution in `4 5 5 6 6 6 ...` which is just `rep(1:3, 1:3) + 3`, so we can just combine these two to get the indices for each element of the vector.

```
## use 1:(n - 1) for a length n vector
mat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
v <- c(2, 4, 5)
i <- cbind(sequence(1:2) + (3 - 1), rep(1:2, 1:2) + (4 - 1))
mat[i] <- v
mat

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    2    4
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    5
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

You can see your starting positions in the above code, so we can generalize this logic:

```
f <- function(matrix, vector = 1:3, start = c(1, 1)) {
  i <- sequence(rep(1:nrow(matrix), 1:ncol(matrix))[length(vector)])
  i <- cbind(
    sequence(i) + start[1] - 1,
    rep(i, i) + start[2] - 1
  )
  ## recycle vector so there are no incompatible length errors
  matrix[i] <- rep_len(vector, nrow(i))

  matrix
}

mat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
f(mat, v, c(3, 4))
f(mat, v, c(2, 2))
f(mat, c(2, 4, 5), c(1, 1))
f(mat, c(v, v), c(1, 1))
f(mat, c(v, v, v), c(1, 2))
```